# Deleting .dll files/folders fromOne More Game

Tags: windows-7

To begin, my computer skills(?) are minimal and I am not a gamer. My computer runs Windows7. I downloaded VLC media player, and 'One More Game' piggy-backed onto my computer. Instant uninstall from programs, BUT, the task bar icon remained operative (despite being set to 'Hide icon and notifications'), and all the .exe files and .dll remained. I cannot delete them, as there is an error message says that these files are in use by a running program. Also, these files are opened with 'unknown app'. One website advised getting a 'One More Game uninstaller' but my Dad's name was Billy not Silly, and I take after him! Advice and assistance will be greatly appreciated. thank you. Justin.

Comment: Where did you download VLC from, exactly? Do you still have a copy of the installer? The program you're referring to is usually stored in `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\OneMoreGame`. Try scanning your system using [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean about your father's name being Billy. Here I assume you mean that you didn't think that the "One More Game Uninstaller" program was legitimate.

If you just want to delete the files, I recommend [booting into Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7), then trying to delete the files.

However, based on the issue that you are having (the operating system says that the files are in use), I can assume that the "One More Game" program did not actually uninstall itself properly. For this, I recommend using [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) (get the freeware version- it should work fine). This program should uninstall the program completely. This is also probably best used in Safe Mode.

I might also run a scan with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), since many of these programs that install with others can be quite difficult to remove.

As a tip for the future, be sure to choose Advanced options when installing anything so you can be sure that you don't install additional software. Express installations these days tend to be filled with programs that you don't want/need.

Comment: Revo Uninstaller can't do anything. Winzip Malware, enabled me to disable the program, and that's all. When downloading, I am paranoid, always 'Custom' and uncheck everything. I had problems with VLC, and my local computer shop guided me through 'nitinite' for a safe download. OMG piggy-backed somehow. I shall now try Safe Mode booting. (Billy and Silly, British joke! It means I'm not always a sucker! :) Thank you for your help. Cheers, Justin.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the WinZip Malware Protector software. Did it recognize the "One More Game" program as malware? If so, if it let you remove it that should be all you need. If it only let you disable it, then there should be no need to boot into Safe Mode. Assuming it worked correctly, it should then let you delete the files.

Comment: HOORAY!! I have just used your Safe Boot method, and OMG has gone for good! I am a a fan of PC Pitstop and PC Magnum as security. They slipped past OMG stuff as well. Again, thank you!! Cheers, Justin